# How to write simple mail server in java?

Tags: java, mail-server

I want to write a mail server, but I don't know how. Would you please give me some direction where to search for exmaples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essential reading for implementors of SMTP servers:

- [RFC 821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) (and updates, most recent is [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321))
- [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) (and updates, most recent is [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322))

The Wikipedia article [Simple Mail Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) has a huge amount of additional information and links.

Answer (score 5):

Apache has done that for you. Visit Apache James home page: http://james.apache.org/

Comment: Even if you really want to write your own, and an already-finished solution like this is out of the question, using it as an example might be very helpful.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel...I hope you have added better gripping technology on the wheel. You have to be up to date with RFC's if you want to do it from scratch.